# GitHub Actions does not trigger on push event

Tags: docker, github, dockerfile, github-actions

I have a repository that has two folders and both of them have a Dockerfile inside. Only one of them has GitHub Actions configured to build the Dockerfile. It used to work just fine but now it does not trigger at all.

What could be the reason for it? This is the GitHub Action flow I have built. There are no exceptions.

```
   name: Docker Image CI

on:
  workflow_dispatch:
  push:
    branches: [ master ]
  pull_request:
    branches: [ master ]

jobs:
  build:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest

    steps:
    - uses: actions/checkout@v2
    - name: Login to GitHub Package Registry
      run: echo ${{ secrets.GITHUB_TOKEN }} | docker login docker.pkg.github.com -u ${{ github.repository }} --password-stdin
    - name: Build the Docker image
      run: docker build -t dashboard:latest .
    - name: Tag the Docker image
      run: docker tag dashboard:latest docker.pkg.github.com/test/dashboard/dashboard:latest
    - name: Push the Docker image to the registry
      run: docker push docker.pkg.github.com/test/dashboard/dashboard:latest
```

Comment: Did you rename `master` branch? If you didn't, then what was the action that you did, which should have produced a trigger event? Was it a push to `master` branch?

Comment: @anemyte the branch is named master. It was created before the changes in GitHub

Comment: Does the manual trigger (with the `workflow_dispatch`) work?